# Dealing with excess kurtosis via GLM in R

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, kurtosis

I am working in R with a dataset that produces an error distribution under OLS with minimal skew, but excess kurtosis around 2.  After researching the problem on Google for a day I've sorted out that the best approach to performing a regression is to use the Generalized Linear Model with a suitable error model, but I'm stymied trying to figure out which error model to use.  Hypothetically a t-distribution with 7 degrees of freedom would get me the right kurtosis, but given my N is over 1000, I’m skeptical.  Any suggestions on either which error model to use would be appreciated.

Comment: There's many, many posts on site that explain that there's no assumption in regression that relates to the marginal distribution of the response; the y-variable on its own might look like it was drawn from almost any continuous distribution (arbitrary location-mixtures of normals are a pretty broad family of distributions)

Comment: Ok, I’m going to correct the question, because the error distribution is effectively identical to the data distribution; I have not dealt with this problem previously and chose the wrong aspect to emphasize.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals? What are your variables? How many do you have? Are you trying to test something, to predict, or something else?

Comment: Can you explain why a large sample size would make you skeptical of something like a $t_7$ distribution of errors?

Comment: I’m attempting to determine whether a teacher training in my county is having any effect on growth in reading test scores of students taught by participating teachers.  I’m controlling for a bunch of student-level variables including gender, race/ethnicity, special education status, socioeconomic status, timing of test within the school year, relative age of student compared to grade level peers, etc.  I’ve got several dozen independent variables once the categorical dummies are factored in.  The qqplot of the residuals highlighted the kurtosis problem, and R’s descdist() gave the details.

Comment: My skepticism of the applicability of the t7 distribution simply comes from my understanding that the t-distribution should approximate normal when applied to a dataset with 900+ degrees of freedom as exists here, and thus that it would be damned odd for the error distribution to mirror the t restricted to only 7 degrees of freedom.  I’m fully prepared to be told that that represents a misunderstanding on my part of the properties of the t-distribution.

Comment: I am releasing my skepticism on the t-distribution for two reasons.  First, empirical:  I've been able to generate qq plots comparing my residuals to the theoretical t-distribution at low degrees of freedom, and they match well.  The second is intuitive:  my dependent variable is the difference between pre/post scores for each student on the same test, i.e. the difference in samples from two highly-correlated random variables, and the t-distribution arises from multiple pulls from a single normally distributed random variable.  It doesn't seem a stretch to have a t-distribution show up here.

Comment: Hey, @Glen_b, I realize this is a bit weird, but if you promote your question above into an answer, I'll accept it, as continuing to investigate put me onto the correct solution.  I eventually wound up applying the t distribution as explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642312/how-do-i-use-t-distribution-with-glm-in-r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To briefly expand on my question:

> Can you explain why a large sample size would make you skeptical of something like a $t_7$
>   distribution of errors?

It doesn't matter whether you have a large sample or a small sample, the shape of the distribution of the population from which the sample was drawn would be the same.

Large sample size would impact the distribution of a *mean* of values, not the shape of the distribution of the individual errors. A $t_7$ has a particular form of heavy tail.

[I would however, be somewhat suspicious of assuming student scores have a t-distribution at all; they're typically discrete and bounded. One might ignore the discreteness in some cases, but the boundedness would tend to be more of an issue.]

Comment: As I noted above, I suspect the t distribution was a consequence of the independent variable in question being the difference of two test scores per student, Fall and Spring, each of which is likely a normally distributed random variable on its own with a mean of each student’s actual degree of mastery at the time of testing.

Comment: @dspitzle I can't follow the reasoning there, sorry. How would a difference of two normal values in $x_i$ (IV) lead to a t distribution of the *error* term in $Y_i$? (the error term is assumed to be independent of the value of the $x$'s). While test scores obviously cannot be normal (they're bounded and discrete), let's assume that they're reasonably approximated by normal distributions ... I don't see how -- even assuming an arbitrary dependence structure between them, or indeed any distribution you like on the difference -- would lead to t-distributed errors in the DV.

Comment: This an intuitive explanation, so it’s undoubtedly flawed, but imagine each student’s 2 tests were taken when no true skill growth had occurred.  In this case each student would have two observations of a single random variable which for arguments’ sake we’ll assume had normally distributed error.  The mean of those errors would be distributed as t with 2-1=1 df.  With the actual tests occurring over an interval of potential skill growth, it seems reasonable the difference  of those errors might be t distributed with more degrees of freedom.  Not at all rigorous, just my thought process

Comment: I should note that due to my rustiness with this level of statistical work I keep conflating the distributions of the variables and of the errors in my explanations, which resulted in me editing my original question, and also undoubtedly contributed to your confusion about my logic.  I’m aware of the difference and will hopefully be more precise in my writing going forward.

Comment: "*would have two observations of a single random variable which for arguments’ sake we’ll assume had normally distributed error. The mean of those errors would be distributed as t with 2-1=1 df*" --- How do you get from the first sentence to the second? If the test scores were *jointly* normal, the mean of several such differences would have a normal distribution, not a t-distribution. If the test scores are not jointly normal, you'd have to explain what dependence structure you assume that could lead to a t-distribution.

Comment: Based on your objections, I'm probably garbling this from Wikipedia (the most convenient resource I've got at the moment):  "If we take a sample of n observations from a normal distribution, then the t-distribution with \nu=n-1 degrees of freedom can be defined as the distribution of the location of the sample mean relative to the true mean, divided by the sample standard deviation, after multiplying by the standardizing term \sqrt{n}." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution

Comment: Okay sure ... but you did not divide by any sample standard deviation in your previous comments. Without that, you don't get a t-distribution

Comment: I take that as a sign that my intuition as to >why< the errors were t-distributed is probably wrong.

Comment: If anybody else wants to take a stab at giving a theoretical model for why the error distribution of pre/post-test score growth would tend to follow a t-distribution with low df, go to town...

Answer (score 9):

From your question, I think you may be labouring under a common misunderstanding about the relevance of large N in a statistical model.  The relevance of having a large N is that it allows you to approximate using asymptotic theorems such as the central limit theorem (CLT).  Roughly speaking, this theorem (actually it is a group of theorems) says that when you take a bunch of random variables from any non-heavy-tailed* distribution, and you make a mean quantity out of them, that mean quantity will have a normal distribution when N approaches infinity.  Remember: this theorem asserts normality of *the distribution of the mean quantity* - the underlying distribution of the individual random variables is still whatever it was.

In the context of regression, this means that the error terms can be non-normal, but even in this case, the *coefficient estimators* (which are mean-type quantities based on the error terms) for the parameters of your model will be approximately normally distributed when N is large.  If the underlying error distribution is indeed a T(7) distribution, then making N large does not change this.  The CLT does **not** say that the distribution of underlying error terms becomes normal if N is large.

Another way to think about this is as a *reductio ad absurdum*.  If you take the view that having large N means that the error distribution should be normal, that is tantamount to saying that we can never observe large numbers of non-normal random variables.

In any case, this means that there is no cause for scepticism of the proposed error distribution based on the size of N.  If the residuals fit closely to a T(7) distribution, then this is a plausible fit.  Not only is there no cause for scepticism, but the fact that you have a large N and you are finding that a T(7) distribution fits this well, means that your empirical estimate of the error distribution is likely to be quite close to the “true” distribution, and so you can be pretty confident that it is a good estimate.

My suggestion would be to fit a regression model with a T-distribution as the error distribution, allowing the DF parameter to be a free parameter that is estimated from the data.  Once you have fitted this model you will get parameter estimates, including an estimate of the DF.  You should then generate an empirical residual density plot (i.e., a plot of the kernel density of the studentised residuals) and superimpose the estimated T distribution over the top of this to see if it looks like a plausible distribution.  You can also try a QQ plot comparing the empirical quantiles of the studentised residuals to the quantiles of the T distribution.  These diagnostic plots will help you see whether the T distribution is a plausible error distribution or not.

Cheers,
Ben.

- Technical Note: The CLT generally requires that the underlying distribution have a finite variance, which rules out certain heavy-tailed distributions.  In your case, where you have a T-distribution with 7 DF, this distribution has finite variance and so the CLT would apply.
- Another Technical Note: The CLT also requires either that the random variables are independent, or at least not too dependant.  This condition is not relevant here.

Comment: I think your answer focuses on estimating the mean.  The OP is interested in estimating kurtosis. The point about large sample size is about consistency of the estimate.

Comment: You were quite right as to my confusion.  Thanks for spelling it out so well for future visitors.

Comment: Michael, Ben basically had the right point:  I had no grounds for skepticism about the error distribution based solely on N, and it was largely an outgrowth of the confusion he remarked on at the start of his answer.

Comment: That is an extremely common confusion in my experience.  Many textbooks on CLT draw attention to this confusion precisely because it is so common.  Glad my answer helped.

Comment: You can fit a model with $t_7$ errors, but it won't be a GLM